# Triggering an event on specific days and times

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an existing data structure I'm forced to work with whereby scheduled events are saved by day of week and hour.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and an ASP.NET console application (temporarily) to trigger.

Trigger times are stored as boolean values in the database.

Example:

```
SendMonday            bit   Unchecked
SendTuesday           bit   Unchecked
SendWednesday         bit   Unchecked
...
=====================================    
Send0000              bit   Unchecked
Send0100              bit   Unchecked
Send0200              bit   Unchecked
Send0300              bit   Unchecked
...
```

What would be the best approach from both a theoretical and programming perspective in order to trigger the event at the specific time?

My approach involved storing a 'LastProcessed' date in the database and doing a lot of manual work but wondered if there was a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to run a scheduled task on an hourly basis to check for events that need to be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you able to elaborate on this. Perhaps projecting the scheduled email requests into some kind of queue for later processing via the agent?  I don't like relying on SQL Server Agent but I guess it has its uses.

Comment: It depends what the task actually is - if it involves some kind of non data behaviour - eg sending emails, - then an external scheduled application or polling service might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for scheduled task with a stored procedure at the back end. Scheduled job should execute the stored procedure, sproc would look into the table with invocation times and decide if and what you need to execute. You can hook-up external programs into stored procedure if you need to do that.

Alternatively, if you don't want to depend on sproc and sql server agent, you can write all your logic in your console application, and execute your app from Windows Task Scheduler. So your app would get data from scheduling table, decide if and what to do and proceed as required.

My preference would be with the second approach - easier to maintain, but it really depends on your requirements and environment.